# Match two sphere plots in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

Suppose I have two plots on the unit sphere in Matlab. I would like to be able to match the two plots in the following sense: I want to overlap them and see if I have the same thing. In order to do this I would like to fix one of the plots and rotate the other by hand.

> Is it possible to do this in Matlab: rotate a part of the plot while keeping another part fixed?

Comment: fix one of the plots is easy, rotate the other by hand is hard, ask Matlab to automatically overlap the 2 plots might be easier.

Comment: project from a sphere to 2d using your favorite projection method (i.e. use map projection). Matlab has this built-in, then "rotation" is just translation of the maps....